# I want to search a word from a file and replace it with another value in file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

I want to search a word from a file than on behalf of that search i want to replace a word in that file.
Below is the content in the file on which search and replacement has to done(this is .csv file) Let the file name be test.csv-:

```
A,B,C,D,E
unix,123,crap,as,d
dpk,123,crap,as,d
shy,123,crap,as,d
ghn,123,crap,as,d
unnix,123,crap,as,d
```

Below is the command I am using -:

```
grep -rl 'unix' test.csv | xargs sed -i 's/crap/linux/1'
```

Output of this command -:

```
A,B,C,D,E
unix,123,linux,as,d
dpk,123,linux,as,d
shy,123,linux,as,d
ghn,123,linux,as,d
unnix,123,linux,as,d
```

But i want that sed should replace the word crap from the row which contains unix not from whole file . Please help in this regards. 
Or i s there any other way to do this.
Output I desired-:

```
A,B,C,D,E
unix,123,linux,as,d
dpk,123,crap,as,d
shy,123,crap,as,d
ghn,123,crap,as,d
unnix,123,crap,as,d
```

Comment: does `unix` have to be in the beginning of the line ?

Comment: it doesnot make any impact Abu i guess

Comment: it kinda matters, cause if I know where the targeted word is located, it could simplify the regex that will replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i want that sed should replace the word `crap` from the row which
>   contains `unix` not from whole file

You can say:

```
sed -i '/unix/s/crap/linux/' test.csv
```

---

EDIT:

If you intend to perform replacements only in the *filtered* output produced by `grep`, you can say:

```
grep 'unix' test.csv | sed 's/crap/linux/'
```

In order to save the output to a file, add a redirection:

```
grep 'unix' test.csv | sed 's/crap/linux/' > new.csv
```

Comment: I want sed to execute after searching a particular row from a file ,so I am trying to do search by grep.When the row is searched sed should replace matched word from the file for that row only.

Comment: @abhinavdixit See edit.  It'd help if you mention the desired output.

Comment: But motive is not to make new file. Also if i do as per you mentioned above by redirecting into a new file than new file will contains only 1 row but i want replace should be done on the same file.

Comment: @abhinavdixit Could you add the desired output to your question?

Comment: i had made edit in my question i had just mentioned the sample output which i desired.

Comment: @abhinavdixit I assume that you didn't see my answer.  Saying `sed -i '/unix/s/crap/linux/' test.csv` would produce exactly the same output as you've indicated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/crap/linux if(/\bunix\b/)' your_file
```